# Access 2007 Report: Code or no Code?

Tags: ms-access

I've been researching around a lot and I just can't find something I think should be very easy to someone with very little experience with Access 2007.

I am trying to create a report.  The db has two tables.  One with account, name and address.  The other has account and product Id.  The tables are joined on account.  One customer/acct can have several product Ids.

I need to create a mailing that will have rich text in the body and list per account/customer the products they have.

I keep running into having the rich text(body of letter) showing each time the product Id is listed.  Do I need to create something in code first?  Like an array with the product Id so I can have it as one variable per account/customer?  If so, where should I create this?  In code, macro or expression builder?

Getting kind of frustrated I guess.  I'm tempted to write something in C# as I have enough knowledge I think to make this happen, but I prefer to keep it all in Access.  I might also be asked to keep it in access and c# is not what is used currently where this project is being built.

Comment: This sounds like you should be running a mailmerge with Word and Access.

Answer (score 1):

Rogue:

You should use a page header on your report containing the formatted customer/account info, probably: "Dear Account:... "  You're treating each id as a separate form letter.  What you want is each customer to get the letter via treating the customer as a page header and group footer, while the id's go into the details.

Then, the one or more  products would be in the detail section.

The closing of the letter would be in the group (customer info) footer: "We look forward blah., blah sincerely.....

Then, set the property of the group footer to "force new page after section", meaning when you get to a new customer, eject to a blank page and start printing another letter.

Hope this helps.